# Struggling with this sequences question

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm looking at a guided tutorial on a course that I'm doing around sequences and series, and I'm really confused by one part. Here is the provided text:

```
A sequence xn is defined by:

x1 = 2

xn+1 = k ÷ xn for n ≥ 1

where k is an integer.

a) Write x2 in terms of k.

b) Hence, show that x3 = 4/k


We’ll work through each part in turn.

a) Write x2 in terms of k.

We have

x2 = k ÷ x1

= k/2

b) Hence, show that x3 = 4/k

This means that

x3 = 2 ÷ (k/2)

   = 2 × 2/k

= 4/k    

as required.
```

What is really confusing me, is on the step-by-step for b), where are they getting the 2 from for the 2 ÷ (k/2)? Surely it should be k ÷ (k/2)?

I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but have been trying to think it through for ages now and just can't work it out.

Comment: Yes, in that expression we should have $x_3=k\div x_2$ so, since $x_2=\frac k2$ we should have $x_3=k\div \left(\frac k2\right)=k\times \frac 2k=2$.  Regardless of inputs (excluding division by $0$), this sequence is periodic with period at most $2$.  I don't understand what they wrote.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was going crazy and not understanding basic maths. It was like they worked out k, and then substituted it in but left the other k just to confuse matters

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand as it isn't a typo.  Ignoring problems with $0$, $x_3=x_1$.  It's not a function of $k$ at all.  Well, mistakes happen.